# Using Gulp with Babel error for import

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use babel to compile ES6 code
I have tried with one simple file (routes/users.js) like following

```
import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

export default router;
```

I've added to the gulp file the following

```
gulp.task('esconverter', () => {
    return gulp.src('routes/users.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I've added the task to default

```
gulp.task('default', ['esconverter' ,'nodemon'], () => {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

when I run it (gulp.js)  I got the following error

```
/Users/i0/Webs/blog10/bl/routes/users.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from 'express';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
```

I see in the **dist/users.js** folder that created the file that was generated

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _express = require('express');

var _express2 = _interopRequireDefault(_express);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var router = _express2.default.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

exports.default = router;
```

How can I overcome this issue?

**update**

This is my project structure:
The starter point of the project in bin/www 
express is in app.js in the root

[image]

in addition I changed my gulp file to this and still the same error :(

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], () => {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: {
            target: "http://localhost:4000",
            ws: true
        },
        files: ["public/**/*.*"],
    });
});



gulp.task('esconverter', () => {
    return gulp.src(['bin/www', 'routes/users.js', 'routes/index.js'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


gulp.task('nodemon', cb => {
    let started = false;

    return nodemon({
        script: 'dist/www'
        //script: 'bin/www'
    }).on('start', () => {
        // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
        if (!started) {
            cb();
            started = true;
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['nodemon','esconverter' ], () => {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

**update 2**

I try also with the following code

```
gulp.task('esconverter', () => {
    return gulp.src(['./**/*.js', '!./node_modules{,/**}', './gulpfile.js', 'bin/www','!./dist'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

which create the following dist folder and still the same error above

[image]

Comment: Do you have `babel-preset-es2015` installed?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff - I did npm install babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev and created .babelrc file with {
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}

Comment: And, just to confirm, you have installed `express` via npm too?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff - Yes of course :) , the code is working if I change the syntax to ES5 ...,any idea what im missing here?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff - please see my update if you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run babel in your entire codebase and make sure you're running node on the compiled main file.

If you have a index.js file, you should change your task to something like this:

```
gulp.task('esconverter', () => {
    return gulp.src(['index.js', 'routes/users.js'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And you should run `node dist/index.js`.

---

**Update based on source code update:**

If you move all your source files into a `src` folder, you can have your task like this:

```
gulp.task('esconverter', () => {
    return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.json', './src/**/www'])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And in your nodemon you point to: `'dist/bin/www'`.

The important part here is, to keep the same file structure inside the dist folder has you have in your source, otherwise the require paths will fail.

Comment: Hi Thanks , My project is build with started point bin/www.js and also in the root project  i've app.js so how should I handle in this case?

Comment: I've changed the project like you said and still same error ,please see my update...

Comment: does your `bin/www.js` references your `app.js`? if yes, you should add your `app.js` to the esconverter as well... but i foresee that you might have issues with the fact that your `dist` folder does not has the same structure that your main files are expecting... some requires might break.

Comment: Hi in addition this is my very simple project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8fd7J9aXGXaRGVTajRUYlpoVE0/view?usp=sharing please see if you can help ,Thanks! (you just need to do npm install and gulp in the command line...)

Comment: Hi, I had it running in my machine, and updated the answer with what I had to change. After having everything like this, I had a issue that might not be related with the question being discussed here.

Comment: Hi I tried it but I got the same error , can you share your updated version ? I dont have in my code src....

Comment: I will not be in the computer for the next 6h. I moved all of the source files into the src folder. But anyway I'll upload it when I get home.

Comment: I think its happen since the json file is also missed in the dist folder , I try with what you suggest './src/**/*.json' and also with '/*.json' and its not working I dont see the json file in the dist folder , any idea how to put it there? btw the json is a valid json file I've double check it...

Comment: Yes, I also moved the JSON file to the src folder

Comment: ohh you put all the files in the src folder ? can you please share it or give instructions which files I should remove to the src folder ?

Comment: Ok the problem is with the json since when I copy it manually to the dist folder its working since when I run the task the config file is missing (I put it in the src folder that I created under the root of src...) any idea why it doest able to copy this json file ?

Comment: Do you have `'./src/**/*.json'` in your es6 task?

Comment: Did you able to see it in your dist folder (the config.json) ?

Comment: I close this question since the orig error is not showing anymore and open new with the config.json issue , please have a look if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329156/gulp-copy-config-json-to-dist-folder-is-not-working , thanks!